# Using robospice for long running http requests

Tags: android, download, robospice

Is there any example of using [robospice](https://github.com/octo-online/robospice) library for downloading large files? I've read there is BigBinaryRequest for it but what if there will be connectivity lost/ device reboot duing file download? After next execute call download will resume/restart or request success listener will fire with reference to damaged (not completly downloaded) file?

Maybe someone have experience of using robospice for such requests.

P.S. I know that there is native DownloadManager in Android, but I think using robospice is easier. Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: If download exit due to a IOException (which is plausible for connectivity lost) the response won't be cached and your file will be downloaded again from scratch next time you make the request.

Comment: What if I'll execute the same request (same destination file, same url) while previous one uncompleted?

Answer (score 0):

@rciovati got it right, your download, if interrupted will be lost as RS won't be able to load the result from the cache. Or even worse, you could have receive an uncomplete InputStream from the cache. In that case you should remove the cache content by yourself (using the spicemanager's method to achieve it is pretty easy).

If you download twice a large input stream using the same cache key, there is no protection against that in RS. Your cache will get corrupted.

This answer may give you the feeling that BigBinaryRequest is poorly designed and not working, but according to my own experience, it works fine in all cases I met up to now.

Comment: I'm already using it's subclass (return Boolean instead of inputStream, cause caching inputStream were leading to OOM). The only thing is annoying is that next request will execute only after the previous one is completed.

Comment: Hmm, I'm just using the same code as in sample app. Didn't know that thread number is customizable.

Comment: Override getThreadCount in your service, you must create your own service for that, a pre-set service won't do. Check the wiki, the starter guide will explain it, it's not very difficult.